# Is there a simple manage.py command that I run with django-celery to daemonize celery in production?

Tags: django, deployment, celery, daemon, django-celery

I've followed the guide at celery project page to daemonize the process with no success so far. I was wondering if there is a simple manage.py command to ease this process. I'm using django 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

You could try use [`python manage.py celeryd_detach`](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/management/commands/celeryd_detach.py)

Comment: It's not working for me, somehow. Could you please tell me a way to figure out why?